# Discord.py send image inside @bot.event

Tags: python

Im trying to make it so the bot sends a message like " is back!", and im using the on_member_update method, but I have no idea how to make it send the message.

Here is my code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if not str(before.status) == "online" and str(after.status) == "online":
        bot.send("cruzes")

bot.run("token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably easy to find in the documentation, but to send to same channel use this function:

```
await channel.send(message)
```

The channel id is a predefined variable somewhere earlier in the code. It would look something like this.

```
channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
```

Comment: should i replace channel_id with something? if so, what and how do i get it?

Comment: You can get the channel id from discord by right-clicking the text channel and clicking copy id

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1umxZV5poeBx3bAdse6IHYxsDOsmAztGd i dont see that option though

Comment: You have to have admin perms on the server in order to get it. Ask someone who is or try it on a server you own.

Comment: I do own the server

Comment: You must not have developer mode enabled. Go to user settings, appearance, and then turn on developer mode